# like query not working if string has symbol '&'

Tags: mysql, sql-like, ampersand

I have a table name as test. In test table there is column test1. test1 column has string value "abc & def" and i have create a string variable $str = "abc & def". When i'll try to execute like query (select * from test where test1 like '%$str%').
this will give nothing in result. can any one help?

Comment: Your variable doesn't get resolved. Post your exact code of how you're trying to execute the statement.

Comment: LIKE should work fine with ampersands.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `test1` LIKE '%abc & def%'  works.

Comment: no this is not working actually my string is this 'IMR E & T S.r.l.'

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming you are using core (vanilla) PHP:

Something like below :

```
$esc_str = $db->quote($str);
// this is for PDO; for MySQLi use $db->escape_string($str) instead
$qry = "select * from test where test1 like '%$esc_str%'"
```

use the below :

```
$esc_str = $db->quote($str);
$qry = "select * from test where test1 like '%".$esc_str."%'"
```

or

```
$esc_str = $db->quote($str);
`select * from test where test1 like "%$esc_str%"`
```

this example converts php variable to https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is dead open for SQL injection!

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya so what is your suggestion if its core PHP and mysql ? . Obviously $str should be validated first

Comment: Use Prepared statements (either MySQLi or PDO extensions can be used)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - do you mean to say MySQLi is injection proof ?

Comment: Please read about [why parametrized queries (or, prepared statements) are necessary to prevent SQL injection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2469308).

Comment: not working test with this string 'IMR E & T S.r.l.'

Comment: I am using active records in php

Comment: If i am using 'and' instead of '&' in 'IMR E &T S.r.l.' this string then it works fine but i wanna '&' not 'and'.

Comment: @yoganandyoganand ??